# gorm golang one2many same table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a self-reference in a (my)sql table using golang gorm. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Children []*Person `gorm:"ForeignKey:ParentID"`
    ParentID uint
}

func main() {
    /* code to get database connection omitted */

    p := &Person{Name:"Sally"}
    db.Create(p)

    children := []*Person{ {Name:"Jane", ParentID:p.ID},
        {Name:"Tom", ParentID:p.ID}}

    for _, child := range children {
        db.Create(child)
    }

    var children2 []*Person

    db.Model(p).Related(children2, "ParentID")
}
```

The code is failing with an error "reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value".

Does anybody know how to get this relationship working using go gorm?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately gorm have added lately this feature (reference: [here](http://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Self-Referencing)).

In your case should be like this:

```
type Person struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Children []*Person `gorm:"many2many: children;association_jointable_foreignkey:children_id"`
}
```